# create instance by full name in Python

Tags: python, class, reflection, instance

Rephrased:

I want to create class instances by class names. Those names are saved in a json configuration file in a sequence. They are defined in python files. Some class have the same name but in different folders.

Use a simple example as below: 
Folders as:

```
folderA/User.py #define class User

folderB/User.py #define class User
```

In mymain.py, I read from the config file the name in sequence, say, "folderA.User" , "folderB.User", they're strings.

I want to convert those strings into corresponding instances when running. Note the config file may change. That's why I need create dynamically.

OK, I won't use globals(), how can I do?

Comment: `globals(...)` is not a function that takes arguments, nor do you need to use it here. Just import `folderA` and `folderB`, then reference `folderA.User.User` and `folderB.User.User`.

Comment: I'm curious, what did you hope `globals("folderA.User.User")` would achieve? Is there a web page or piece of documentation that gave you the impression that the function could be used like this somewhere?

Comment: The User string is read from a configuration file.

Comment: @Martin I found some page telling me globals()[classname] can create instance from its name at run time. I need to do this.

Comment: Note that in that example no arguments are passed to `globals()`; the function returns a Python dictionary object with all the global names for the current module as the keys; `globals()[classname]` applies `[classname]` to that dictionary, so it looks up the value associated with a key that `classname` references.

Comment: The dictionary returned by `globals()` will not contain names that were not assigned to before (or were bound in other ways, like with `import`), and you won't find attributes of other objects in that dictionary, so while `'folderA'` might exist in it after `import folderA`, you won't find a key with the value `'folderA.User'` or `'folderA.User.User'`.

Comment: @Martijn Yes, you're right. I didn't find anything useful after printing globals(). Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Martijn OK, I got your meaning in the second comment. Create all object directly and mapping their name string using dictionary when reading config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actualy globals() func. is a dictionary
Its syntax is as follows:

```
globals() -> dictionary
```

for example

```
>>>globals()['z'] = 23

>>>z
23

sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/application/app/folder')
import file1
import file2

sys.path.insert(2, '/path/to/application/app/folder2')
import file3
import file4
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try this code each yourfile.py

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/application/app/folder')
import file
```

Comment: No. I don't understand the meaning adding path. May I use globals("User") create instance dynamically?